# Android browser, what is this menu called?

Tags: android, android-source, android-browser, android-menu

[image]

I am trying to find the corresponding code to the buttons on the top, but I dont know where that code is, and I am having a hard time finding it because I dont know what this menu is called.

Anyone know what this menu is called (or its components) or where the code that controls cut/copy/paste in the browser resides? It would be extra helpful if you knew of any Android-x86 related changes to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action Bar

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's the ActionBar - a longterm feature made more useful and controllable in the last couple of versions. You can add your own custom buttons to it, defining their behaviour, as well as more complex controls (ie search bar). See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html for more info.

Comment: Specifically that one is the Contextual Action Bar -- used for temporary menus and buttons for text selection and that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

These are simple option menu just coming in action bar but it comes in action for tablet and for phone it comes as in previous version .........

as in [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

but if it is on phone it may be custom action bar...